# loopback: logging queries executed by datasource

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop

Is there a remote method in Loopback data-juggler or any other loopback component which will let me log the query that is executed by the datasource.

Eg: If i'm using MySQL connector, then when MODEL_NAME.findById() is called, i should be able to get

> SELECT * from DATABASE_NAME.MODEL_TABLE where id = WHATEVER_ID

Similarly for MongoDB, it should return equivalent mongo query
It'd be great if i am able to log query.explain() of mongo here itself

I've tried running my app as DEBUG=loopback:connector:* node . as suggested here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/loopbackjs/rpii8R8iUkw

It helps, but i'm not able to understand if the query used mongo indexes or not.

Is there a better alternative where i can get response from the datasource and trim it to my requirements? (like just showing if index was used or not)

Answer (score -2):

about query execute command, maybe you can see this document [Connector hooks](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Connector-hooks.html)

in my application, I use after execute to log insert and delete method

```
return db.observe('after execute', function(ctx, next) {
  let sql = ctx.req.sql;
  let isInsert = _.startsWith(sql, 'INSERT INTO');
  let isDelete = _.startsWith(sql, 'DELETE FROM');

  // logic code

  return next();
});
```

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)