# Loopback connector hook

Tags: javascript, loopbackjs

I want to log all insert sql statements of my model.
According to the loopback [documentation](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Connector-hooks.html#before-execute) the connector hook is ideal for this.

**model.js**

```
var _ = require('underscore');
module.exports = function(Model) {
  //...
  var connector = Model.getDataSource().connector;
  connector.observe('after execute', function(ctx, next) {
    var sql = ctx.req.sql;
    var isInsert = _.startsWith(sql, 'INSERT INTO');
    next();
  });
}
```

I am getting

> getDataSource is not a function

However if I do `console.log(Model)` I can see the function.

*Idea taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42088404/loopback-logging-queries-executed-by-datasource)*

Comment: @rmlan good catch. It was a typo. fixed

Answer (score 0):

Model.getDataSource is not a valid role for the Model.
You can create a boot script to accomplish the desired:

```
module.exports = function (server) {
     var myConnector = server.datasources.MyDataSource.connector;
     return myConnector.observe ('after execute', function (ctx, next) {
         // ...
     });
};
```